# All parameters are bound BUT I get 'Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I know that it is because I'm not binding all the variable that needs to be binded, but I can not see which one ?

```php
    public function addFile($data, $file)
    {
        if (!file_exists(dirname($data['path_to_file']))) {
            mkdir(dirname($data['path_to_file']), 0755, true);
        }
        $this->database->query("INSERT INTO files   ( 
                                                        published_by,
                                                        about_client, 
                                                        path, 
                                                        title, 
                                                        category,
                                                        type,
                                                        size
                                                        )
                                    VALUES              (
                                                        :published_by,
                                                        :about_client,
                                                        :path,
                                                        :title,
                                                        :category,
                                                        :type,
                                                        :size
                                                        )"
        );

        $about_client = $this->queryDatabase("SELECT users.id 
                                                    FROM users INNER JOIN 
                                                                clients c on users.id = c.user_id 
                                                    WHERE c.id = :id",
                                            ":id", $data['patient_choosen'])[0]->id;

        var_dump($about_client);
        pretty_print($data, 1);
        $this->database->bind(':published_by', $data['id_of_publisher']);
        $this->database->bind(':about_client', $about_client);
        $this->database->bind(':path', $data['path_to_file']);
        $this->database->bind(':title', $data['title']);
        $this->database->bind(':category', $data['category_choosen']);
        $this->database->bind(':type', $data['file_type']);
        $this->database->bind(':size', $data['file_size']);

        if ($this->database->execute()) {
            move_uploaded_file($file['files']['tmp_name'], $data['path_to_file']);
        }
        if (file_exists($data['path_to_file']))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Here is the dump of the data that I bind :

```
string(1) "3"
array(15) {
  ["id_of_publisher"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["patient_choosen"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  }
  ["category_choosen"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["path_to_file"]=>
  string(36) "/var/www/app/data/deepadaptation.pdf"
  ["title"]=>
  string(14) "deepadaptation"
  ["tag_choosen"]=>
  string(1) "2"

  ["file_size"]=>
  int(179132)
  ["file_type"]=>
  string(3) "pdf"
}
```

it should insert correctly, but it's not. It worked fine before, the only thing I changed is the bind to about_client, it was `$data["patient_choosen"]`
before, but it did not match what I wanted to do so I replaced it with a query.

Comment: you forgot to bind **:id**

Comment: I suggest fetching the `$about_client` data *before* making the `INSERT` query. Otherwise, you're attempting to bind `$data` values to the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @tim I bind **:id** in my function queryDatabase.

Comment: i didn't see you had 2 queries there .. @showdev is correct you need to finish one before starting the other

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what `queryDatabase()` does. You may be able to save the `INSERT` result in a variable, like: `$insertQ = $this->database->query("INSERT...` and then bind to that: `$insertQ->bind(':published_by'...`

Comment: Yep, putting it before the INSERT did the work !